# Predict parametric function for Feynman integration method

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I recently started learning integration by differentiating under the integral sign method (or Feynman's integration method). The main trick is to choose appropriate dominating function (as the main theorem used dominated convergence theorem under hood)

Like for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ we choose $e^{-bx}$ because $\frac{\partial }{\partial b}e^{-bx}=-xe^{-bx}$ which will cancel out $\frac1x$ from the integrand and apply integration by parts.

Now, my question is, how to predict this dominating function? Or at least for the following ones:

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty e^{\left(-\frac{x^2}{y^2}-y^2\right)}dx\\
&\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(xy)}{x}dx\\
&\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+p)^{n+1}}\\
&\int_0^\infty \cos^2 x dx\\
&\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2(x^2+1)}dx
\end{align}
$$

I can complete the integration (after getting the parametric form). I just want to know the intuition for predicting the function or parameter insertion.

Comment: that second integral doesn't converge, neither does the 4th one

Answer (score 1):

As for the integrals where the integrand takes the form of a trig function  over a polynomial, we can often parameterize like this
$$I(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{T(tx)}{P(x)}dx$$
Here's a basic example
$$I(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin{(tx)}}{x}dx$$
Take the Laplace transform
$$L[I(t)]=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{x^2+s^2}\frac{dx}{x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+s^2}=\frac{\pi}{2s}$$
When we take the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s}$ we get one, so we get that $I(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all t. The Laplace transform often works better than differentiating for these types of integrals. It rationalizes our integrand, and then it just comes down to taking the inverse transform